# Splunk Mint: Failed to archive dSYMs for "MyApp" to "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crashlytics, splunk

How to fix this error?

Splunk Mint: Archiving "MyApp" to "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/MyApp.zip"
  adding: MyApp

zip error: Interrupted (aborting)
Splunk Mint: Failed to archive dSYMs for "MyApp" to "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms"
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 252

Second error is

Splunk Mint: Archiving "MyApp" to "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/MyApp.zip"
  adding: MyApp (deflated 68%)
Splunk Mint: ERROR "400" while uploading "/tmp/splunk-mint-dsyms/MyApp.zip"

Comment: It's working before?

Comment: Yes working. But stopped suddenly.

Comment: @ObjC did u find any answer to solve this issue?

Comment: @Ramakrishna remove run script from build settings.

Comment: Can u explain me a bit clearly.
What happens if i remove it? If i remove the run script then we have to upload DSYM files manually.

Comment: Yes, you can remove run script.. Run script is for upload DSYM automatically. if we remove run script then we need to upload DSYM manually. Please  check answer written by Pradip Vanparia for steps

Comment: I'll give a try. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove run script added for auto upload DSYM file.
And manually upload DSYM for crash report symbolication.
Please check for how to upload DSYM manually.

**Download dSYM bundles using Xcode Organizer after archiving your app**

1. In Xcode, from the Xcode menu select Window > Organizer.
2. In Xcode Organizer, click the Archives tab.
3. Under iOS Apps, select your app from the list.
4. From the Version column, select the archive for your app, displayed as App Version (Build Uuid).
5. Click Download dSYMs to download the dSYM bundles from Apple.

**Compress and upload dSYM bundles to MINT**

6. In Finder, find the dSYM bundles (archive files) you just downloaded.
7. Right-click the archive file and select Show package contents.
8. Open the dSYMs folder.
9. Compress each dSYM file named with your app's build UUID to a ZIP file.
10. Open MINT Management Console by logging in to mint.splunk.com.
11. Select your app project.
12. Click the Settings dashboard.
13. Under Project Settings, click dSYMs.
14. Click Browse & Upload, then navigate to and select the dSYM bundles you compressed.

For more info check out [docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintIOSSDK/5.2.x/DevGuide/Configureyourprojectforsymbolication)

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me was contained here:

[Run Script Phase after dSYM is generated with Xcode 10 (on build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205108/run-script-phase-after-dsym-is-generated-with-xcode-10-on-build)

Adding `sleep 5` to the top of:

```
iOS/Pods/SplunkMint/SplunkMint.framework/Resource/splunkmint_postbuild_dsym_upload_script.sh
```

A hack, yes, but better than having to disable the upload completely IMO.